# How to redirect looped plots to a grid

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I know that my question has been asked several times, but it took me already too much time and I can't find the solution, even if I am sure it's quite simple...
The data is coming from 3 separate dataframes which are shaped the same, to get the boxplot I had to transpose the data and make some other changes...

This is my code, hope it's not too minimalistic:

```
columnname = list(cm)
max = len(columnname)-1
for i in range(0,max):
    cm2 = cm[columnname[i]]
    vz2 = vz[columnname[i]]
    models2 = models[columnname[i]]
    columns = [cm2, vz2, models2]
    name = str(cm2.name)
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.boxplot(columns)
    ax.set_ylabel('$')
    ax.set_title(name)
```

How can I get it to a chosen grid? Just using (2,4) in subplots is not working. --> AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'boxplot'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are pretty close.... one change is you need to define the subplot() before the loop and mention the number of array (2,4) you need. Inside the loop, you need to indicate the ax[row, col]. I have updated your code and used some random numbers to generate the same below.

```
cm = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(100, 8))
vz = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(100, 8))
models = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(100, 8))

columnname = list(cm)
max = len(columnname)-1

fig, ax = plt.subplots(2,4,figsize=(15,12))

for i in range(0,max+1):
    row=i/4  #Identify the row number
    col=i%4  #Identify the column number
    cm2 = cm[columnname[i]]
    vz2 = vz[columnname[i]]
    models2 = models[columnname[i]]
    columns = [cm2, vz2, models2]
    name = str(cm2.name)
    ax[int(row), col].boxplot(columns)
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer my question by providing this marvelous solution! At least I was close, still some way to go... I will use this as a solution to show the plots. A future possibility would be to show the plot in one plot in groups of three. But this for another time... thx again